# How to configure Weblogic users in security realm with WLST offline?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I have a weblogic domain,

1. I added some users to the default security realm (myrealm) with web console.
2. Then I shutdown weblogic.
3. And run an offline WLST script which readDomain(...) from this domain directory and created a template with writeTemplate(...) named template.jar
4. Run another WLST script to create a new domain from template.jar
5. I Startup new domain.

Then I found users in myrealm are missing.
I am new to weblogic and WLST. It seems WLST did not export users/password to template?
How can I make security realm users/password pre-configured with WLST? So I does not need to create many users/password by manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do this in online mode because of the nature of Weblogic's embedded LDAP. You can do this via the console if you go to:

`Home >Summary of Security Realms >myrealm >Users and Groups>Migration tab`

And do an export of the domain and import into the new domain.

This can be done with online wlst like:

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic', 't3://origDomain:7001')
domainRuntime()
cd('/DomainServices/DomainRuntimeService/DomainConfiguration/FirstDomain/SecurityConfiguration/FirstDomain/DefaultRealm/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultAuthenticator')
cmo.exportData('DefaultAtn','/tmp/your.ldif', Properties())

connect('weblogic','weblogic', 't3://newDomain:8001')
domainRuntime()
cd('/DomainServices/DomainRuntimeService/DomainConfiguration/SecondDomain/SecurityConfiguration/SecondDomain/DefaultRealm/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultAuthenticator')
cmo.importData('DefaultAtn','/app/userdata/abc.ldif', Properties())
```